# Is the packets loss caused by LAN or WAN? Its very confusing any idea?

Tags: networking, network-programming, voip

I have a ISP provider (Telenet). Who provides via DHCP public ip to there DSL modem. From that modem we have RJ45 cable connected to a 24 port switch.

Now in our local network:
- from switch port 1, we have one voip phone
- from switch port 2, we have another voip phone

Each has default gateway 78.21.232.1 and subnet mask 255.255.240.0. But different public ip such as 78.21.235.x or 78.21.232.x series.

Question/confusion:
When i send packets from our local network to our local public ip's, is the traffic going to ISP default gateway? Or its straight inside our Switch network?

But i saw many times i gets packet loss in those voip phone diagnostics. Making me completely confused now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got several places to look for more information about where your packets will go. The first is your *routing tables*:

```
$ ip route
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.121  metric 1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  proto static
```

This shows which interfaces (`virbr0`, `eth0`) will be used for packets destined to which CIDR ranges. The `default` entry at the bottom is used for everything that doesn't match one of the more specific routes. Since my LAN is `192.168.0.0/16` then I would expect all packets sent to hosts on my LAN to *not* go through a gateway device (the `via ...` in the last entry).

The `arp` tool can also help you find out where your packets will go:

```
$ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.0.146            ether   00:06:7f:27:45:80   C                     eth0
192.168.0.1              ether   00:0f:66:4c:01:f8   C                     eth0
```

My machine knows two other MAC addresses on the network right now, and can send packets to them directly. If the HWaddress is duplicated for several entries, they are probably on the other side of a gateway, or it is a machine with multiple IP addresses advertised on a single NIC.

I'm not sure how to help with the packetloss problems; try moving switch ports, swapping cables, etc. Maybe you've got a bad port, that can happen from time to time. Try to isolate which pairs of machines have packetloss problems. (And don't try to `ping -f` to Mac OS X machines, they rate limit ICMP replies. It's funny once you know about it...)

Comment: Packet loss is fixed by just enabling the embedded Video conferencing device Ethernet interface to settings to "100Mb full duplex" or "Auto". arp -a shows 78.21.232.1 (dynamic ISP default gateway), 78.21.235.2 (video device 1, type dynamic), 78.21.238.3 (video device 2, type dynamic), 224.0.0.2 (one of the video device , second lan interface, type static). I am still confuse, when video device 1 send/receive packets, to video device 2, are they sending straight or there packets being switched from ISP default gateway to end points?

Comment: @Iam, if I read that correctly, it looks like packets can be routed directly between the two VoIP devices. Of course, they could be implemented to always send traffic upstream; can you do a quick test, initiate a call between them, and then yank the upstream cable for a few seconds? >:->

Comment: still works, when i yank the ISP cable to the switch.